# Why does TinyMCE insert <span> </span> between (django) {% %} tags?

Tags: django, tinymce, html

My application features a CMS for editing Django templates.

Whenever I type something like

```
{% sometag %}
```

TinyMCE will actually store

```
{%<span>sometag</span>%}
```

Is there any way to prevent TinyMCE from doing this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok! I got it. The  elements were only being added when I pasted content. And there's a TinyMCE initialization setting to stop this

```
         'paste_remove_spans': True,
```

Comment: for rails (tinymce-rails gem) you can make this a key in config/tinymce.yml :)

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the HTML view and adding the code from there. That should stop TinyMCE from changing anything.

Comment: I was hoping for a better solution...otherwise, why use TinyMCE at all?